# How to add multiple solution reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is more like a beginner question, but till now I have worked on small C# projects and I know how to add a separate project.

I will create a class library, and add reference of it as per needed, and then I am good to go. I will have something like below:

```
Project Main -> references Project Temp1 
             -> references Project Temp2
```

But all this when built will form ONE `.sln` file.

**Question:** how can I link separate `.sln`? So, I have 5 separate Visual Studio solutions, and I want to add reference, how to achieve it? Is it possible for one `.sln` file to link to another `.sln` file?

**Edit**: I created a sample application `A1`, and another application `B1`. And now when I go to Project A1 and click on Add reference why don't I see project `B1` there?

[image]

Comment: solution file is mainly a collection of projects and some start up configurations. And a visual studio instance opens a sln file at a time. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. You add a reference to a project, not a sln file.

Comment: Ok, I create 3 SEPARATE console Apps. ConsoleApp1, ConsoleApp2, Console3. All have their separate .sln file obviosuly. Now suppose I want to refer ConsoleApp2 in ConsoleApp1, how to acheive it?

Comment: With class library I add, I am already in ConsoleApp 1, I jsut add the library and then the reference.

Comment: you can still add an existing project to any solution, may be you need a common project that'll be shared in all 3 solutions. Be careful when you edit the project, it'll be applied to all the solutions.

Comment: @AD.Net: Can you kindly see my edit. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your projects are targeting compatible framework versions. For example, you can't reference a .NET 4.6 project from .NET 4.5. There are several ways they could be incompatible so keeping the frameworks the same between your projects will make things easier.

Comment: @M.Babcock: No No, nothing complicated, I just want to know basic way to add multiple projects. Every framework, and everything is same

Comment: @M.Babcock: See the screenshot I added, I want to see project B1 there.

Comment: @Unbreakable It is a common problem when working with big projects (where one solution with some hundreds projects isn't practical and have terrible performance). Personally the easiest way to solve this (unless you want to add references to compiled DLLs in the output folder - a pain and possibly a source of errors) is to use **NuGet**. You can setup an _internal_ server to your organization and each solution publishes one or more packages you can then reference in other solutions. It take a few hours to setup but it scales pretty well.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : Do you mind sharing any link related to all this info. I will just read it once. Becasue in my company they have 5 separate soltutions and they are all linked. So I am wondering how they have done it.

Comment: From the dialog you posted you can add a reference to a physical file (Browse button), if you pick it from the output directory of another solution then you are done. However you need to keep all solutions to rebuild them when a dependency is changed (or to put binaries in source control OMG). You also need to _remember_ to rebuild when necessary.

Comment: Nuget makes things much more easy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview

Answer (score -1):

Your screenshot shows the reference manager with item "Projects > (current) Solution" open. This list shows all projects in currently opened solution. To see your "B1" project here, add it to solution first:

- Solution Explorer
- Right click on Solution
- Add > Existing Project

Comment: And which file I need to add once I reach to the B1 project. I only see the `.csproj`, rest all folders for B1 is empty

Comment: I see 3 folders bin, obj, properties and `.csproj` file. And all these folders are empty

Comment: The csproj file is your project definition. Add it. Don't care about bin and obj. folder.

Comment: But... please note, the "right way" is using NuGet. (Or simply place all your apps in one solution)

Comment: Can you kindly send me any link which talks about adding it via NuGet, I will read the links.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti posted a great link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview